# Solana Deserialization

Tags: data, deserialization, borsh, instruction

Anymore has some resources or something on how to implement borsh deserialization for Solana instruction data?
I'm having the issue that I don't know the length so I get an error when trying to call try_from_slice any way on how to call the try_from_slice_unchecked.

Lets take this as a minimal example:

```
#[derive(BorshSchema, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
struct Payload {
    purchase_qty: u64,
    expected_price: u64,
    seller: String,
}

let (&tag, rest) = input.split_first().ok_or(Error::Unexpected(format!("Invalid Instruction")))?;

let data = Payload::try_from_slice(rest).unwrap();
```

where the last command fails with the following input data
`70c23f6334935530e803000000000000ff47030000000000057a4e3d6acf2f5218f24947801d10baadcc78e1abf15d838e0b4f46d6013288`

i know there is the function `try_from_slice_unchecked` but its only available inside the solana-crates can i somehow implement it also or parse the instruction-data more `generic`?

Comment: If you're trying to deserialize account data then you must first remove the descriminator from the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a problem of:

1. Different instruction lengths/content which i coverd with multiple structs and length checks of the instruction-data
2. An incorrect mapped type:

```
seller: String
```

which should not be a `String` but a `PubKey`

represensted in a solana-sdk free project like this:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
struct Pubkey([u8; 32]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If that `Payload` struct is the only input that your program can receive, then this should work:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
struct Payload {
    purchase_qty: u64,
    expected_price: u64,
    seller: String,
}


pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    match Payload::try_from_slice(&instruction_data) {
        Ok(payload) => your_fn_here(payload),
        Err(_) => Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),

}
```

If you want to leverage multiple instructions, you can use an enum with structs as variant args, like this:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
struct Payload {
    purchase_qty: u64,
    expected_price: u64,
    seller: String,
}

#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
struct PayloadTwo {
    purchase_qty: u64,
    seller: String,
}

#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
enum MyInstruction {
    PayloadInstruction(Payload),
    PayloadTwoInstruction(PayloadTwo),

}

pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    let instruction = MyInstruction::try_from_slice(&instruction_data)?;
    match instruction {
        PayloadInstruction(data1) => some_fn(data1), // Payload struct
        PayloadTwoInstruction(data2) => some_fn(data2), // PayloadTwo struct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually deserialize some struct (without Anchor), I suggest bytemuck, structs are Plain Old Data (POD):

```
pub fn get_payload_from_bytes(v: &[u8]) -> &Payload{
    bytemuck::from_bytes(v)
}
```

Note your struct has to implement POD (you may need to replace your String with a fixed-len char array to satisfy POD/Zeroable more easily):
`#[derive(Pod, Zeroable)]`

If these are anchor structs, you can remove the 8-byte discriminator and do the same:

```
    let acc_data = &ctx.accounts.acc.try_borrow_data()?[..][8..];
    let payload: &Payload = get_payload_from_bytes(acc_data);
```